# Delete Row from all google sheets based on value of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to achieve a script that will delete a row based upon a string in a cell within that row,

I can achieve my mission if I want to name each individual sheet, however my sheets are constantly changing names, so this would mean updating the the script daily.
I have tried to create a loop, but that does not seem to work either, any suggestions?

The script I am working on is below.

```
function RemoveInvoiced() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pxWr3jOYZbcwlFR7igpSWa9BKCa2tTeliE8FwFCRTcQ").getSheets();
for (var k=0; k<ss.length; k++)
var values = ss[k].getDataRange().getValues();

var rows_deleted = 0; 

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {

        var value = values[i][j];

        var row = i + 1 - rows_deleted;

        if (typeof value === 'string') {

            var result = value.search("INVOICED");

            if (result !== -1) {
                ss.deleteRow(row);
                rows_deleted++;
            }
        }  
    }
}
};
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a sufficient problem definition. **What happens** and what did you **expect to happen**. What does your debugging indicate?

Comment: Also note that if you were to debug your script **at all** you would notice that your very first `for` loop - the one over all your sheets - is malformed.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the sheet name to access them, you could access them by Id.
The id will never change as long as you don't delete the sheet, even if you change the name.

You'd first have to get the sheets Id, a simple function could do that for you

```
 function getId(sheet){
     Logger.log(sheet.getSheetId());
 }
```

Once you have gotten your sheet ids, you can make a function that will open the right sheet by the ID

```
function openSheetById(doc, id){
    var sheets = doc.getSheets();
    for(var i = 0; i< sheets.length ; i++){
         if( sheets[i].getSheetId() == id)
              return sheets[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then you can access the right sheet.

```
function myFunc(){
     var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pxWr3jOYZbcwlFR7igpSWa9BKCa2tTeliE8FwFCRTcQ");
     var id = // your id here
     var sheet = openSheetById(doc, id);

     if(sheet){
          //do other stuffs
     }
}
```

Comment: OP's problem is due to missing braces. Should be closed for being due to a typo